# Qlikview -- Using If with a variable in expression

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to use an if statement with a variable in my expression and I get no results. The variable works when I use the variable on it's own but when used with the if I get no results.
I have tried:

```
if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018',$(vAvgOrderCost),0)
if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018',sum($(vAvgOrderCost)),0)
sum($(vAvgOrderCost)if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018',0))
```

Nothing seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Variables in QlikView are used as a text replace feature, so be carefull. If your variable hold a value like 1,345 an expression like "if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018',$(vAvgOrderCost),0)" will be translated into "if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018',1,345,0)" which by itself will be a syntax error.

Something like :

```
Num(if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018','$(vAvgOrderCost)','0'))
```

would be a safe way to go.

Answer (score 0):

the if() syntax should work like this if(test,true,false)

So looking at your examples I suspect this is what you are trying to do

```
sum(if(OrderQtr='Apr-Jun 2018',$(vAvgOrderCost),0))
```